# Jquery, prototype, mootools and rails 3 fancy uploader

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, prototypejs, mootools, fancyupload

I'm using **Rails 3.2.6** and trying to integrate [Rails S3 Fancy uploader](https://github.com/iwasrobbed/Rails3-S3-Uploader-FancyUploader) and I think it's probably a misunderstanding with how I'm using prototype, jquery, and mootools at the same time, or just migrating it to a newer version of rails.

I've got jQuery in noconflict mode right after including the asset pipeline *(prototype.js & mootools.js libraries are in the /assets/javascript folder, as well as all the source files for 'fancyuploader' similar to how the /public folder is oriented in the github repo)*:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
<script type="text/JavaScript>
jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

However, I am still getting a lot of undefined errors, and I think it has to do with the order the assets are being loaded onto the page.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Window] has no method 'addEvent' script.js:10
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Window] has no method 'addEvent' script.js:10
Uncaught ReferenceError: Class is not defined FancyUpload2.js:15
Uncaught ReferenceError: Class is not defined FancyUpload3.Attach.js:15
Uncaught ReferenceError: Class is not defined FancyUpload3.S3Uploader.js:27
Uncaught ReferenceError: Fx is not defined Fx.ProgressBar.js:13
Uncaught ReferenceError: Swiff is not defined Swiff.Uploader.js:14
Uncaught ReferenceError: Class is not defined Uploader.js:13
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined prototype.js:6719
```

It looks like mootools and prototype aren't available to the scripts required the create the 'FancyUploader'

---

The project runs just fine in **Rails 3.0.7**, with the assets in a *public folder* and *haml* template engine in the source (I'm using erb, but this is a JS problem I think), however, I also noticed *prototype doesn't seem to be referenced* in the authors includes??

```
= javascript_include_tag( 'mootools.js', 
                              'fancyupload/source/Fx.ProgressBar',
                              'fancyupload/source/Swiff.Uploader', 
                              'fancyupload/source/FancyUpload3.Attach', 
                              'fancyupload/source/FancyUpload3.S3Uploader' )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well. you have a problem here, your stack is not compatible.

- jquery + prototype = ok
- mootools + jquery = ok
- mootools + prototype = fail

The reason is simple - both are prototypical and whereas you can namespace the `$` and make sure that plays nice, you cannot namespace the Types protos and neither MooTools nor Prototypejs try to hide / namespace their global object exports on top of that, so there will be inevitable clashes.

Time to rethink what you use, having 2 frameworks is frowned upon, having 3 is overkill.

Comment: Ah, I see, so the original author probably isn't using `prototype` at all! Hence the reason I don't see it referenced. I think I need to look more into why the `Class` prototype isn't being instantiated out of either library or crashing. I think I'll stick with just `mootools` since it looks to be what the original script used.

Comment: Well, the original fancyupload is by Harald (digitarald) formerly of the mootools-core team so yeah, no jquery, no prototype :)

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't try with 
http://mootools.net/forge/p/mooupload

Support the new HTML5 chunk uploading, flash upload and normal html4 upload. It has a nice progress bar and allow you to upload several files at same time (Plus multiple file selection with HTML5 and Flash upload method).

Mooupload uses "document.id" and not $, so It should work together with JQuery.